# How to style the cursor shadow using CSS?

Tags: css, cursor, shadow

On my page, I can see the box of the `div` container. I only want a shadow to be displayed behind the cursor. How can I achieve this?

CSS style:

```css
#shadow {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2rem var(--beton);
    background-color: var(--beton);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="shadow"></div>
```

JS:

```js
const mouse_shadow = function(event) {
    document.querySelector("#shadow").style.top = event.pageY + `px`;
    document.querySelector("#shadow").style.left = event.pageX + `px`;
}

document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mousemove", mouse_shadow)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to trigger the addEventListener with an event, like body `onload`. I'm unfamiliar with the color `--beton` so I used a placeholder

```js
let shadow = document.querySelector("#shadow");

const mouse_shadow = function(event) {
  shadow.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';
  shadow.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
}

document.querySelector("body").onload = function() {
  this.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse_shadow)
}
```

```css
#shadow {
  --beton: #2986cc;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem var(--beton);
  background-color: var(--beton);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="shadow"></div>
</body>
```